# How can one join files with seperating data in bash?

Tags: bash

So one can easily join files in bash with cat:

```
cat *.txt > all.txt
```

But what if one wants to insert something between the input files, like for example a linefeed?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Requires GNU `sed`:

```
sed -s '$G' *.txt > all.txt
```

append a line of 8 dashes and a newline after each file

```
sed -s '$a--------' *.txt
```

You can use your sed '$d' with that

Compare to these:

Insert a line of dashes before each file:

```
sed -s '1i--------' *.txt
```

Do the same, but without a newline after the dashes:

```
sed -s '1s/^/--------/' *.txt
```

Put a line of dashes on the end of the last line of each file:

```
sed -s '$s/$/--------/' *.txt
```

Surround each file with curly braces:

```
sed -s -e '1i{' -e '$a}' *.txt
```

Comment: Elegant solution for inserting linefeed, I made a small modification to only have the linfeeds between the original files not at the end: 

sed -s '$G' *.txt | sed '$d' > all.txt

But can this method also be used to insert other data, to be more in line with the general question?

Comment: @Roger: `sed -s '$a--------' *.txt` would append a line of 8 dashes and a newline after each file. You can use your `sed '$d'` with that. Compare to these: `sed -s '1i--------' *.txt`, `sed -s '1s/^/--------/' *.txt`, `sed -s '$s/$/--------/' *.txt` and `sed -s -e '1i{' -e '$a}' *.txt`

Comment: could you add these options to the answer?

Answer (score 8):

As a one-liner with subshells:

```
( for i in *.txt ; do cat $i ; echo 'separator here' ; done ) >all.txt
```

Here's what the subshell executes split into script-style lines:

```
for i in *.txt
do
cat $i
echo 'separator goes here' 
done
```

In this example the separator acts like a footer; add a header by adding another `echo` before the `cat`.

Comment: There is no need for the subshell, and you should use double quotes around the variable expansion to protect any whitespace in the filenames. `for i in *.txt; do cat "$i"; echo 'stuff'; done > all.txt`

Comment: Can this be modified to not insert the separator at the end of the result file, only between the original files?

Comment: @Roger: `files=(*.txt); indices=(${!files[@]}); for i in ${indices[@]}; do cat "${files[i]}"; if [[ $i != ${indices[@]: -1} ]]; then echo "separator"; fi; done > all.txt`

Comment: `catWithSep() { sep="$1"; shift; first=''; for f; do test -n "$first" && echo "$sep"; cat "$f"; first=no; done; }; catWithSep separator *.txt`

Comment: @Chris: nice one!